# Set UIViews separately in Storyboard instead of added one on the top of another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, autolayout

In my app, I am using `Storyboards`. There are two `ViewControllers` in it. In the first `ViewController`, there are many different `UIViews`. `UIViews` are being used as screens. For transition from one view to another, I have written a UIView's `animateWithDuration` block.

In my `Storyboard`, I find it very difficult to set the UIView's content like Buttons, ImageViews etc. I have to hide all of the views and only then can I set the View which I want, as all of them are in the same `UIViewController` and same size too. And now with the Autolayouts, it becomes really difficult to set Contraints etc. Is there any convenient way to do so :

- Create separate `UIViews` as `XIBs` and load and unload them programatically? Is it memory wise alright? Is it a good approach?
- Can I do something directly in Storyboard? Like create `UIViews` and connect them to `Storyboard` instead of making one `UIView` on top of another etc? Create something like segue etc? As done to connect TableView's cell with "DetailedView" etc
- Any other better approach?

Comment: why is it difficult ? You can do the same using document outline in xcode. To avoid confuse, you need to give the names to your UIViews.

Comment: For instance, I have to change the UIView which is at the bottom (i.e at the end). I will have to hide all the Views and then change its content or I will have to do it by hit and trial. I can get it from Document Outline, but can't change it visually, because its underneath other Views

Comment: why you have to hide the other views? you can see all the views and their elements in a drop down tree view in xcode. what is the real problem?

Comment: ok....got your problem

Comment: try to see the view heirarchy in xcode after running the app which gives the clear view of your views. this is not the solution but it will help a bit.

Comment: That I can see, but I am looking for some better approach, so that I can set UIViews directly

Comment: better option is to go for xibs. There is no problem in doint that in any aspect as far as i know

Comment: It won't take more memory by loading/unloading them?

Comment: you can simply set it to nil, once you dont need that view and it wont cause the memory related issues

Comment: Right, I will test that. Thanks

Comment: All your issues are solved in Xcode 7. In Xcode 7 you can add UIView in storyboard directly as another view.